# flask-wtf form validation not working for my new app

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've used flask before and I've had working form validation, but for some reason it's not working for my new app. Here is the basic code of the form.

```py
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators,ValidationError

class subReddit(Form):
    subreddit = TextField('subreddit', [validators.Required('enter valid subreddit')])
    next = SubmitField('next')
    change = SubmitField('change')
    user = TextField('user', [validators.Required('enter valid user')])
    fetch = SubmitField('fetch comments')
```

I have subreddit as the validation field, so if it's empty, I want it to throw an error and reload the page.

The HTML:

```html
<form class='sub' action="{{ url_for('sr') }}" method='post'>
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}                    
  <p>
    if you want to enter more than one subreddit, use the + symbol, like this:
    funny+pics+cringepics
  <p>
    <br/>
    {% for error in form.subreddit.errors %}
  <p>{{error}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
  {{form.subreddit.label}}
  {{form.subreddit}}
  {{form.change}}                    
</form>
```

I have CSRF_ENABLED=True in my routes.py as well. What am I missing? When I leave the subredditfield empty and click change, it just reloads the page, no errors. This is an issue because whatever is in the field will get recorded in my database, and it can't be empty.

EDIT

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
form = subReddit()     
rand = random.randint(0,99)
sr = g.db.execute('select sr from subreddit')       
srr = sr.fetchone()[0]
r = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}.json?limit=100'.format(subreddit=srr))
j = json.loads(r.content)     
pic = j['data']['children'][rand]['data']['url'] 
title = None
if form.validate_on_submit():
    g.db.execute("UPDATE subreddit SET sr=(?)", [form.subreddit.data])          
    print 'validate ' 
    if j['data']['children'][rand]['data']['url']:   
        print 'pic real'                
        sr = g.db.execute('select sr from subreddit')       
        srr = sr.fetchone()[0]  
        r = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}.json?limit=100'.format(subreddit=srr))
        pic = j['data']['children'][rand]['data']['url']
        title = str(j['data']['children'][rand]['data']['title']).decode('utf-8')   
        return render_template('index.html',form=form,srr=srr,pic=pic,title=title)
    else:
        print 'not valid pic'
        return render_template('index.html',form=form,srr=srr,pic=pic)
else:
    print 'not valid submit'
    return render_template('index.html',form=form,srr=srr,pic=pic)           
return render_template('index.html',form=form,srr=srr,pic=pic)
```

Comment: Can you show the code from the view that actually uses the form?

Comment: I will add what I have in an edit, but I am messing with it a lot because nothing is working. When  I enter an invalid subreddit, instead of reloading the page or anything, it just throws an error at the pic variable because it cant get json from an invalid sub

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a number of problems.

The most important is that validation occurs in the POST request view function. In your example this is function `sr`. That function should create the form object and validate it before adding stuff to the database.

Another problem in your code (assuming the above problem is fixed) is that after validate fails you redirect. The correct thing to do is to render the template right there without redirecting, because the error messages that resulted from validation are loaded in that form instance. If you redirect you lose the validation results.

Also, use `validate_on_submit` instead of `validate` as that saves you from having to check that `request.method == 'POST'`.

Example:

```
@app.route('/sr', methods=['POST'])    
def sr():
    form = subReddit()
    if not form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('index.html',form=form)
    g.db.execute("UPDATE subreddit SET sr=(?)", [form.subreddit.data])      
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Additional suggestions:

- it is common practice to start your class names with an upper case character. `SubReddit` is better than `subReddit`.
- it is also common to have the GET and POST request handlers for a form based page in the same view function, because that keep the URLs clean when validation fails without having to jump through hoops to get redirects working. Instead of having the `sr` function separately you can just combine it with `index()` and have the action in the form go to `url_for('index')`.

Comment: thanks for this help, I will mark this as my answer, but I am still having issues I don't have time right now to work out. Hopefully soon I will fix it, but I have updated my code if you want to check it

Comment: It's still wrong. Don't use `request.form['subreddit']`, use `form.subreddit.data` instead. Also, instead of checking for `request.method == 'POST'` move up the `validate_on_submit` call to take its place. You should only update the database after the form validates succesfully.

Comment: I updated the code one more time, but it doesn't work. When I leave the  field empty, the correct code runs, and it reloads the page with an error message. But, when I enter a valid text, it still fails? I cant get my code in the form.validate to work, it just gets ignored because form.validate is not picking up correct text

Comment: Are you rendering {{form.user}}? That field also has a validator attached, if you don't render it to the form the validation will never work.

Comment: ah thanks, I have a working app now. I separated the form into 2 different kinds and than every thing worked

Answer (score 3):

Flask-WTF adds a new method onto the form called [`validate_on_submit()`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WTF/#api-changes). This is like the WTForms `validate()` method, but hooks into the Flask framework to access the post data. The example given on the Flask site is:

```
form = MyForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash("Success")
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

Because you're just using validate(), the form is trying to validate without any data (which, of course, will fail). Then you're redirecting. Try to use `validate_on_submit()` as shown above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding your question. Perhaps edit the answer with the change that you made?